# phonegap android simulator camera does not work?

Tags: cordova, camera

I've tried to load up the following barcode scanner code:
http://www.mobiledevelopersolutions.com/home/start/twominutetutorials/tmt3

and after successfully setting up everything, I opened up the simulator and noticed that the camera wasn't working. Instead I was getting a black/white blocks.  Is this normal? Is it possible to have the camera for the simulator be my laptop?

Answer (score 1):

What you are seeing is normal. The Android SDK provides an "emulator" not a "simulator" (yes, there is a difference). The emulator just shows you the checkerboard pattern when you call the camera. When you take a picture it always returns you the same Android jpg as the data.